# Differences in Linear Regression Model Performance with StandardScaler vs. Min-Max Scaler

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, scaling

I am working on a linear regression problem where I've noticed a significant difference in model performance when using different scaling techniques: StandardScaler and Min-Max Scaler. I would appreciate insights and opinions from the community on this matter.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, r2_score

data = pd.read_csv("/content/weight.csv")

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data["Gender"] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data["Gender"])

category_mapping = {}
category_mapping["Gender"] = dict(zip(label_encoder.classes_, label_encoder.transform(label_encoder.classes_)))

inputs = data.drop("Weight", "columns")
output = data.drop(["Gender", "Height", "Index"], "columns")

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
inputs_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(inputs)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inputs_scaled, output, train_size=0.8)

model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Model application.
gen = int(input("Enter Gender : "))
hght = int(input("Enter Height : "))
indx = int(input("Enter index : "))

input_value = scaler.fit_transform([[gen, hght, indx]])
y_pred = model.predict(input_value)

r2 = r2_score(y_test, model.predict(x_test)) * 100
```

I have encountered an interesting issue with a linear regression problem. When I use StandardScaler to scale my input features, the model predictions appear to be more accurate, but the R-squared (R2) score is lower. On the other hand, when I use MinMaxScaler, the R2 score is higher, but the predictions seem to be less accurate.

I would like to understand the potential reasons behind this discrepancy and gather opinions on which scaling technique is more appropriate in this context. Additionally, if there are any steps I can take to improve model performance with either scaling technique, I'd appreciate any insights.

I've tried both the techniques but the issue still persists.

The expected output for my program would have been the [average correct prediction (not accurate)] and along with it a good r2 score.

Answer (score 1):

One possible source for the discrepancy that you see between the two scalers is an error in your code: you should not `fit_transform` your test data (`input_value`) but rather only `transform` them based on the `scaler` trained on the training data. The effect of this error on the predictions may be different for the two scalers, which may explain the different results.

For linear regression (when no regularisation is applied, like in the case of sk-learn's `LinearRegression`) the scaling of the features should have no effect on the predictions. Scaling is recommended when the data has extremely large or small ranges for a purely computational reason (because the bad scaling of the features may lead to a large condition number of the linear system that needs to be solved).

See the example below that compares no scaling with `MinMaxScaler` and `StandardScaler`. While the fitted coefficients are different in the three cases, the values predicted for the same input are the same. (Note: if you replace `transform` with `fit_transform` you will see that the three predictors give different results).

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

X = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3]])
# y = 1 * x_0 + 2 * x_1 + 3
y = np.dot(X, np.array([1, 2])) + 3
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print('No scaling')
print('intercept', reg.intercept_, 'coef', reg.coef_)
print('prediction', reg.predict(np.array([[3, 5]])))

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_ = scaler.fit_transform(X)
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_, y)
print('MinMaxScaler')
print('intercept', reg.intercept_, 'coef', reg.coef_)
print('prediction', reg.predict(scaler.transform(np.array([[3, 5]]))))

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_ = scaler.fit_transform(X)
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_, y)
print('StandardScaler')
print('intercept', reg.intercept_, 'coef', reg.coef_)
print('prediction', reg.predict(scaler.transform(np.array([[3, 5]]))))


### gives
No scaling
intercept 3.0000000000000018 coef [1. 2.]
prediction [16.]
MinMaxScaler
intercept 6.000000000000002 coef [1. 4.]
prediction [16.]
StandardScaler
intercept 8.5 coef [0.5        1.41421356]
prediction [16.]
```

Also note that you should not rescale your data prior to applying `train_test_split` but only after, by `fit_transform`ing on the training data and `transform`ing the test data,